# subsonic 3.0 - separate generated code from ActiveRecord.vb

Tags: vb.net, subsonic3

I moved from SubSonic 2.x to 3.0 and noticed that all my classes are combined into the ActiveRecord.vb(cs) file. Is there a way to have my classes generated individually in a separate folder (DAL) as I was doing with 2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design in SubSonic 3.0